# Python Django Template language unpack List

Tags: python, html, django, django-templates, iterable-unpacking

I am trying to pass values from the views.py to the HTML to be displayed but a list is being passed instead of a single value.

I have a random link that should randomly pick an item from the list,

this is the HTML where the item should link to

```
<a href="{{entries}}">Random{{entries}}</a>
```

this is the views.py

```
def rando(request, title):
    items = util.list_entries()
    randomitem = Random.choice(items)
    return render(request, "encyclopedia/view.html", {
    "entries": md.convert(util.get_entry(randomitem))
})
```

this is the error I receive

**TypeError at /wiki/['CSS', 'Django', 'Git', 'HTML', 'Python']**

the random link in the HTML should pass only one of the items on the list.

can anyone help me with a solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
    items = choice(util.list_entries())
    randomitem = util.get_entry(items)
    return render(request, "encyclopedia/view.html", {
        "title": items,
        "entries": md.convert(randomitem)
    })
```

updated the code. works fine now